# Is there JDBC ConnectionPool leaks in Jetty 9.2.3?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jetty

I have a long running Java Jetty (version 9.2.3) Application with DB connections to Oracle. The App runs fine. But, after 24 hours, I found out that number of TCP connections to the Oracle server has increased, and is greater than MaxLimit (4, in my case) that I set for the ConnectionPool.

```
$ netstat -an | grep 1234
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:60373  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   ESTABLISHED 
tcp     2340      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:78482  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   ESTABLISHED 
tcp     2440      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:88418  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   ESTABLISHED 
tcp     2610      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:58264  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:58288  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:40352  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:58145  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   ESTABLISHED 
tcp     1230      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:59334  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   ESTABLISHED 
tcp     2450      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:58287  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   ESTABLISHED 
tcp     1230      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:59333  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   ESTABLISHED 
tcp     1190      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:59340  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   ESTABLISHED 
tcp     1320      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:58480  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:40338  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   ESTABLISHED 
tcp      100      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:59382  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:40952  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:70952  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.178.120.15:60952  ::ffff:218.17.10.11:1234   TIME_WAIT
```

Is there ConnectionPool leaks in Jetty 9.2.3?

Answer (score 2):

Jetty just tracks (in JNDI) and returns the DataSource object that your jdbc support jar creates and maintains.

If there is a connection leak, then its entirely within the jdbc support jar that you are using.

Look into updates for that jar, and/or consider using a proper Connection Pool layer for your DataSource's.

Some possible candidates:

- Jolbox BoneCP - http://jolbox.com/
- c3p0:JDBC - http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/
- Apache DBCP - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Comment: @stones333 How would we know? Link? Quotation?

Comment: That [ConnectionPool](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/ConnectionPool.html) is jetty-client code.  [That fix](https://bugs.eclipse.org/461499) is for its internal HTTP persisted connection pool.  Not related to JDBC, JNDI, or DataSource concepts.

Comment: @stones333 not that we are aware of, it doesn't contain jetty client classes, nor does it depend on jetty client.  It being a commercial, non-opensource project makes discovering that sort of thing difficult.

Comment: Please don't use BoneCP anymore - consider it deprecated in favour of HikariCP (BCP author).

Comment: Oracle also has connection pool known as Universal Connection Pool (UCP).  YOu can download the ucp.jar required from OTN (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)